# Two JPanels on top of each other with horizontal scrolls

Tags: java

So I have this panel positioned at the top (NORTH) side of my frame called menupanel. Inside this panel I have two other panels - topPanel and botPanel (red and black). Inside both of those panels there are several several buttons. I would like to add scrolls (horizontal) like I've shown on the image.

```
menupanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
menupanel.add( topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
menupanel.add( botPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtk0O.png)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. BorderLayout constants have no meaning if the menupanel JPanel doesn't use a BorderLayout.

Comment: Also the tutorials will show you how to use JScrollPanes, and you should try their suggestions first before coming here. If you're still stuck, then please post your best code attempt, and we'll be in a much better position to help you.

Comment: sure but this is not the point ... I got it right in my original code

Comment: [First hit of this Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jscrollpane%20tutorial)

Comment: I've watched many videos and read many forums but still couldn't do it

Comment: Terrible question: How can we help you if you don't show your attempt? Regardless -- please look at the first hit in the link above as it will show you how to use JScrollPanes.

Comment: Ah nevermind I'm just gonna go ahead and knock my head for another 2 hours and probably do it myself. Terrible response to my question ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, I did behave badly, but you're also right, that you should knock yourself out first. And if you're still stuck, do come back, but first read about how to ask a decent question. you really need to show your code attempt as a [mcve], else the best we can do is tell you to "go look at the tutorial".